# Pedestrian network analysis for campus routing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, routing, network

I am working on creating a network analysis routing system for a school campus. As of right now I am just focusing on calculating the network analysis based on 10 buildings. I want the user to be able to find the quickest route to get from one building to the next, so they know how long it will take for them to get to class.

I have tried to use the 'Road Graph' plugin, but I am doing network analysis based off of pedestrians walking from building to building, this plugin seemed more accurate for mobile transportation, not as much walking. I have tried I have had more success at creating a network in ArcGIS, but I am trying to keep this project completely open source. (I am not a very talented programmer, so the least amount of algorithms the better.)

What is the most accurate tool/ plugin/ method for calculating network analysis for campus (pedestrian) routing in QGIS?

Comment: Check the availability of data that exists in Open Street Map for your campus - I think you'll be surprised at the routes that exist in that dataset. From there, I would suggest loading the OSM into a PostGIS database using OSM2PGRouting, and building your queries off of that system...